# Text File Does Not Show Up After Writing

Tags: python

I wrote a function that takes a pdf file, extracts the text and saves it to a text file of the user's choosing. The function works well, however the text file seems to not be created. The function returns no error, therefore I think the file is just not coming up as it should.

```
def pdf_to_text(pdf_file, output_txt):
    file_content = [] # list to save text
    
    # import pdf file, extract text and pass into a .txt
    pdf_reader = PDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
    
    # get page and content
    for i in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
        page = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
        p_content = page.extractText().replace("\n", "")
        file_content.append(p_content)
    return file_content

    # save to text file
    with open(output_txt, "w") as output:
        output.write("".join([i for i in file_content]))
```

Pay attention to the last two lines. I think evertything before those works perfectly; I even ut the content as proof, and it works fine. But the text file is not being created.

## Update

Additionally, without removing the line breaks, I get an output like this:

```
(
g
) (U) 
Release
 
deploying soldiers to 1
st
 
Army for deployment to 
OSR AO.
 
3. (U) 
End State.
```

While it should have come out as:

```
(g) (U) Release deploying soldiers to 1st Army for deployment to OSR AO.
 
3. (U) End State.
```

Comment: Those last two lines never get executed, due to the `return` on the previous line.

Comment: `return` causes the function to exit, so nothing after it will run.

Comment: Wow! That worked!!

Comment: While we're here, any idea why the text is returned as a wide list instead of long? I have a 5 page document, and the text is saved into the text in 6 rows but a wide form. @jasonharper

Comment: Well, you're explicitly removing all the line breaks in the text, so what other result could you expect?

Comment: @jasonharper please see update in main post